# javascript template for showing table body

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using ajax for updating/refreshing the cart when an item is removed from the cart table to show the updated items. ajax functionality and logic is working but could not show the following template inside

```
<tbody class="cart-body">
    {% for furniture in cart.furnitures.all %}
        <tr class="cart-products">
            <td class="action">
                {% include 'includes/carts/remove-furniture.html'  with furniture_id=furniture.id%}
            </td>
            <td class="cart_product_img">
                {% if furniture.first_image %}
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/media/{{ furniture.first_image.url }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="#">
                    <img src={% static 'img/default.jpg' %} alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td class="cart_product_desc">
                <h5>{{ furniture.name }}</h5>
            </td>
            <td class="price">
                <span>Rs. {{ furniture.price }}</span></td>
            <td class="qty">
                <div class="quantity">
                    <span
                        class="qty-minus"
                        <i class="ion-ios-minus-outline" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        class="qty-text"
                        id="qty"
                        step="1"
                        min="1"
                        max="99"
                        name="quantity"
                        value="1">
                    <span
                        class="qty-plus"
                        <i class="ion-ios-plus-outline" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="total_price">
                <span>Rs 49.88</span></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

the following template is shown when user is routed to /carts page but when the update part is done, ajax is used and the template i tried is as following

```
success: function(data) {
    var hiddenCartItemRemoveForm = $(".cart-item-remove-form")
    if (data.products.length > 0){
        productRows.html(" ")
        $.each(data.products, function(index, value){
            var newCartItemRemove = hiddenCartItemRemoveForm.clone()
            newCartItemRemove.css("display", "block")
            newCartItemRemove.find(".cart-item-product-id").val(value.id)
            cartBody.prepend(
                "<tr><td class='action'>" + newCartItemRemove.html() +"</td><td class='cart_product_img'><a href=""><img src="media/"+data.image class='img-responsive'></a></td><td class='cart_product_desc'><h5>"+value.name+"</h5></td><td class='price'>"+value.price+"</tr>"
            )
        })
        cartTable.find('.cart-subtotal').text(data.subtotal);
        cartTable.find('.cart-total').text(data.total);
    } else {
        window.location.href = currentUrl
    }
},
```

How do i prepend the above html inside cartBody.prepend() ? Right now I am getting the error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in that prepend function line.

Comment: Start with fixing the error. Check for quotation marks you use in the string when calling cartBody.prepend() (the part with <a href=""><img src="media/") and I believe there's a mistake in the string <img src="media/"+data.image class='img-responsive'>, too.

Comment: I want to take the idea from you. Should i use selector to add the image or use the same above method? Because, i have to check if there is an image or not, if the product has no image, a default image has to be shown otherwise product image. What you say?